# one css style for landscape and portrait photos

Tags: php, javascript, css

I am displaying images that were shot in both landscape and portrait format. I'd like to style them to always display the longest side of the photo at 500px. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone posted the answer I used and then deleted it for some reason. It's working perfectly.

```
max-width: 500px;
max-height: 500px;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set background-size:100% 100%; (this will make images fill its parent element)
Then you can make the div that has the photo to have width:500px;

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("img/test.jpg");
if($width > $height){
    $newWidth = 500;
    $newHeight = (500 / $width) * $height;
}else{
    $newHeight = 500;
    $newWidth = (500 / $height) * $width;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="img/test.jpg" width="<?php echo $newWidth; ?>" height="<?php echo $newHeight; ?>" alt="Test" />
```